# two points of the longest distance in a convex curve will be the vertices?

Tags: differential-geometry

First we give the necessary definition:
A **vertex** of a curve $\gamma(r)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a point where its signed curvature $\boldsymbol{k}_{s}$ has a stationary point, i.e.,where $d\boldsymbol{k}_{s}/dt=0$.

We have Four Vertex Theorem:
Every convex simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has at least four vertices.

Now, I have a question：
For a convex curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, we define the **distance** of two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ on the curve is $L=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 +(y_1-y_2)^2}$.
If the distance of these two points is the longest on $\gamma(r)$, would these two points will be vertices?

Obviously, it's true for the elipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people who don't visualize Minkowski sums easily, here is a slight modification of the example given by Anton Petrunin. I erased the middle part of an ellipse (original ellipse still shown below in grey), shifted the left part down a bit, and completed the curve with straight lines.

[image: distorted ellipse]

The idea is that because of the shift, the diameter of the curve is attained by a pair of points that are close to, but do not coincide with the vertices of the original ellipse. Hence, the curvature is not stationary there.

[image: diameter]

The corners can be smoothened without affecting anything in the construction, since they are far from attaining the diameter of the curve.

Comment: Thanks,I'm a people who don't visualize Minkowski sums easily. Your counterexample is helpful!

Comment: Anton's counterexample, really. The Minkowski sum with a slanted segment looks about the same as this figure.

Answer (score 5):

No. In fact a curve in general position does not satisfy this property.

To construct a concrete counterexample, 
take an ellipse, nearly round one and take its Minkowski sum with a long segment, which does not go in the direction of its axis.

The curve which bounds the obtained convex set does not satisfy your property.
Smoothen it if you want a $C^\infty$-curve.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I see this is your first answer here, hopefully not the last.

Comment: Your counterexample is helpful! @Anton Petrunin